# Proving $\int_0^1\int_1^xe^{t^2}\mathbb dt \mathbb dx=\frac{1-e}2$

Tags: calculus

How can I prove
$$\int_0^1\int_1^xe^{t^2}\mathbb dt \mathbb dx=\frac{1-e}2$$
without having to use erfi$(x)$?

Comment: change coordinate and use fubinis

Comment: Great guys, thanks all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Use Fubini's Theorem to get
\begin{align}
-\int^1_0 \int^1_x e^{t^2}\ dtdx = -\int^1_0\int^t_0 e^{t^2}\ dxdt.
\end{align}

Comment: Accepting this because it was fastest. Thanks all though..

Answer (score 2):

Let $I$ be the integral. Then changing the order of integration gives
$I=-\int_{t=0}^1 \int_{x=0}^t e^{t^2} dx dt = -\int_{t=0}^1 t e^{t^2} dt  = {1 \over 2} (1-e)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\int_1^xe^{t^2}\mathbb dt \mathbb dx&=-\int_0^1\int_0^te^{t^2} \mathbb dx\mathbb dt\\
&=-\int_0^1te^{t^2}dt\\
&=-\frac{e^{t^2}}{2}\biggr\rvert_0^1\\
&=\frac{1-e}{2}\end{align}$$